submit form input after processing and display returned view in spring mvc
In my spring mvc project, I need to process form input in javacript and then submit the processed input to controller and I want to display the view that is returned from the controller. I have submitted the processed input using fetch api in javascript but the returned view is not being displayed. Anyone can suggest me how to do this ?
I didn't find any useful resource on this.
